# ¿Cómo poder separar la información recibida en los input?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, script, input

He intentado de todo para poder separar los datos obtenidos a través de la base de datos pero no he logrado hacerlo, ¿existe algún método para poder hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

logro que el rut y el nombre aparezcan pero se me duplican los dos datos en ambos input, pero quiero que cada uno se muestre en un input diferente.

Estos son la consulta a la BD y el script de la operación.

```js
 <script>
    document.getElementById("fichaComercial").onchange = function(){alerta()};
    function alerta() {
        // Creando el objeto para hacer el request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
        // Objeto PHP que consultaremos
        request.open("POST", "servicesSC.php");
 
        // Definiendo el listener
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // Revision si fue completada la peticion y si fue exitosa
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Ingresando la respuesta obtenida del PHP
                document.getElementById("rutCliente").value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("nombreCliente").value = this.responseText;
                
            }
           
        };
 
        // Recogiendo la data del HTML
        var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var formData = new FormData(myForm);
 
        // Enviando la data al PHP
        request.send(formData);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $FICHA = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["fichaComercial"]));
    
 
    // Codigo para buscar en tu base de datos acá
 
 
    
    $sqlsi = "SELECT rut_cli_ficha_com, nom_cli_ficha_com FROM fichaclientecomercial WHERE num_ficha_com = '$FICHA'";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sqlsi);
    $dato = $resultado->fetch_assoc();


 
    $rut = $dato['rut_cli_ficha_com'];
    $nombre = $dato['nom_cli_ficha_com'];

    echo $rut;
    echo $nombre;
    
 
} else {
    echo "<p>No se encontro el nombre en la DB!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes separar la respuesta en un arreglo que puedas separar en tu js.
La práctica más común es usar JSON, sería algo como:

```
echo json_encode(array("rutCliente" => $dato['rut_cli_ficha_com'], "nombreCliente" => $dato['nom_cli_ficha_com']));
```

En tu JS deberás convertir el string resultado en un objeto así:

```
let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

para luego colocar los datos en los campos correspondientes.

```
document.getElementById("rutCliente").value = data.rutCliente;
                document.getElementById("nombreCliente").value = data.nombreCliente;
```

Explicación:
En el servidor se imprime en pantalla un string que es formato JSON, eso lo obtienes con JS y luego conviertes de texto a un objeto, los nombres de los elementos son los mismos que se colocaron en el servidor y son los que se usan en "data" para que puedas colocar en cada campo.

Comment: me funcionó de maravillas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda